# how to design db schema of an e-learning platform in dynamodb?

Tags: database, mongodb, amazon-web-services, database-design, amazon-dynamodb

I am designing No-SQL DB schema for an online e-learning platform, plan is to store it in the AWS DynamoDB
This is similar to Udemy, user can access and see all the available courses and users can buy more than one course.

As of now, I am thinking of the schema as below

**User**

[image]

**Course**

[image]

But I am just thinking from the item size limit wise, if in future a single user bought many courses or if a single course have many modules and videos in it which can automatically increases the item size in the AWS Dynamo DB which is max 400KB, I have seen blogs suggesting to split up the item, but wanted to check here for your inputs as well.
So my questions are

1. DB schema wise is it fine the way that I am thinking of?
2. What could be the better way when the entries are many and item size is large?

I am also exploring GraphQL, so that calls will have less latency from the front end, but worry is about the DB design and large items.

Let me know if anyone have their thoughts or valuable suggestions on this :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The data is highly relational (user has one or more courses, a course has one or more chapters, ..), and it sounds like a traditional RDBMS is structure-wise the best fit for this data.

Comment: When using DynamoDB, your data model will be driven entirely by your access patterns.  In order to comment on whether or not you are heading down the right path with your data model, we need to know more about how you plan to access your data.

What are the needs of your application?  For example, fetch courses by user, fetch users by course, etc.

Comment: Hi @SethGeoghegan thank you, I am planning to build a mini project like udemy, so the plan is to fetch courses by the user under my courses & to fetch all courses directly on the home screen on user login. With the current course model, I am thinking if, adding individual modules or videos would be difficult as we need to update the existing dynamodb item each time on new video uploading, and another worry as I mentioned 400kb limit of item, what if courses have more moduels. Let me know if you think of any better way or if I am making any mistake, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modeling one-to-many relationships (e.g. Users to Courses bought) within a single item is a common pattern.  However, if the many side of the relationship can grow large, you will likely want a different approach.  It sounds like you're use case ins't a good fit for this particular pattern.

One way around this limitation is to model the relationship in an *item collection*.  For example, you could model the user and the courses bought within the same partition.  Keeping the data together makes it easier to fetch the data in a single `query` operation.

[image]

In this data model, I created a global secondary index named `courses` using the attribute `GSIPK` as the primary key for the secondary index.  This would let you fetch all courses with a single query of the `courses` GSI.

[image]

Keep in mind that this is just one of many approaches you could take to model your data.  Check out [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIQVJqiSUkE) from AWS Re:Invent about DynamoDB data modeling.  It gives a fantastic walkthrough of some of the key concepts that will help you design your data model.

Comment: Thank you very much @Seth Geoghegan, for the detailed explanation and for sharing the video link, it helped me to understand the DynamoDB modeling better, this makes more sense from the access patterns point of view, I will start with this and enhance it further. Once again, thank you :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped!  Learning how to use DynamoDB can come with a steep learning curve if you're coming from SQL databases.  Stick with it!